# template missing error on link click

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

These are my:
index.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Assign Role', projects_assign_role_path(project) %>

controller file
def assign_role
     @users = User.where.not(id: 1)
  end

routes

get "projects/:id/assign_role" => "projects#assign_role", as: :projects_assign_role

But when i click on this link i am getting following error:
Missing template projects/assign_role, application/assign_role with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are requesting a page to be displayed but it is not there. so you should create a page under app/views

Create "projects" folder under app/views

Then create "assign_role.html.erb" under app/views/projects/